# OR searches not working in feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, feed

This works, returning an HTML page:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa+or+carbon+or+core-graphics+or+core-foundation

This used to work, returning a feed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/cocoa+or+carbon+or+core-graphics+or+core-foundation

That doesn't work anymore, though, and these don't work, either:

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/cocoa%20or%20carbon%20or%20core-graphics%20or%20core-foundation
- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cocoa%2bor%2bcarbon%2bor%2bcore-graphics%2bor%2bcore-foundation&sort=newest
- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cocoa+or+carbon+or+core-graphics+or+core-foundation&sort=newest
- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cocoa%20or%20carbon%20or%20core-graphics%20or%20core-foundation&sort=newest

The second of those is actually linked from the first page.

All of the URLs that don't work return 404.

AND searches (e.g., “cocoa carbon”) do work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that -- we're now checking to make sure tags *exist* before trying to serve up the feed and querying the database.

Guess which "tag" doesn't really exist?  (hint: `or`)

Fixed in source control, will be deployed in 18 hours.

Comment: Is this corrected? I'm seeing the issue trying to perform this via:
http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+or+vim+or+terminal+or+command-line+or+zsh+or+gvim

or 

http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/feeds/tagged/python+or+vim+or+terminal+or+command-line+or+zsh+or+gvim

Or is this only functional for the main stackoverflow site?

Comment: rharding, the last tag [gvim] no longer exists